# Apt-get not installing include files

Tags: apt

usually when I ran a command such as

```
sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev libnetcdf11 libnetcdf-bin
```

I would get installed both the netcdf.h and the netcdf.inc files. One usually in some variant of /usr/lib and the other under /usr/include

If I run the same command under Ubuntu 16.04 I only find netcdf.h under /usr/include. No other file netcdf.xxx file.

This is really weird...anyone has an idea why that's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, well, apparently `libnetcdf` is only for C, for FORTRAN I have to install `libnetcdff`. Embarassing.

Answer (score 1):

In the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/n/netcdf/netcdf_4.4.0-2/changelog) of the Ubuntu package [`libnetcdf-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libnetcdf-dev), corresponding to the version `1:4.1.3-1~exp2`, there is tracked the change:

> Splitted C/C++/Fortran bindings for a better and sane migration path
>           towards 4.1.3 and beyond. Also the CF library now lives in its own
>           binary package. Note that all libraries now provide their own 
>           SONAMEs and API versionings.